# Can you remove a file from Mercurial without removing it from the filesystem like Git?

Tags: git, mercurial

I've got some files in a repo that I don't want tracked, is it possible to remove them without removing the actual files from the filesystem?

This would be equivalent to git's `rm --cached`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `hg forget <file>` if files have just been added, however if the files have already been committed use `hg rm --after <file>`.

The help is a bit misleading, it should be `hg rm --do-not-touch-the-filesystem`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `hg forget` is what I was looking for according to [this](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#forget).

This will mark a file so that it is no longer tracked after the next commit.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove the file **from Mercurial history as well**, here's a stackoverflow question on how you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558365/mercurial-remove-file-from-all-changesets/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply ignore them by placing them in a .hgignore file in the folder.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html

Comment: I've ignored them but they're already tracked in the repo and have changes so are showing up.